# Get Moshi adapter from a generic Type - Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, moshi

I'm trying to set up a Moshi adapter so that I can get any model that I pass as a generic. So far I'm having issues getting the class from `T` generic, IDE says `Cannot use T as a reified type parameter. Use a class instead`.

Any ideas how to solve this?

```
val model = getModel<SimpleModel>()    

private fun <T> getModel() : T? {
  val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
  val adapter = moshi.adapter<T>(T::class.java)
  return adapter.fromJson("{\"name\": \"this_guy\"}")
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `private inline fun <reified T> getModel(): T` as your function declaration.

Declaring the type parameter as reified allows you to access its class object.